# How can I create colored-background to text in css?

Tags: c#, html, css, web, html-helper

like a highlighted text.
and also - how can I put animations in my website?
I've tried using "text-background-color" (which does not seem to work so it is probably not true haha). A new b to html here..

Comment: It would really help if you can share your code and can elaborate what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

## Text Background Color

To color on every text, use this CSS trick(not really a trick):

```
p{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

The `p` is for the tag, `<p>`. The things inside the curly brackets are the properties of the element. In this case, the background-color only covers the text and not the whole website.

This works too:

```
<p style = "background-color: yellow;"></p> <!-- <span> works too -->
```

### Ids and Classes

Id's can work on one element, while classes work on multiple elements.

```css
/** Classes are used with a period, id's are used with a hashtag(#). **/
.yellow{
  background-color: yellow;
}
#blue{
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<p class = "yellow">This paragraph is highlighted yellow!</p>
<p class = "yellow">This one too!</p>
<p id = "blue">This paragraph is highlighted and the only one who is highlited blue.(unless you make a new class or id that has the same property)</p>
<!-- Classes can range to only one element, but coders don't usually use classes as id's -->
```

## Animations

I am not familiar with animation, and they are pretty complex. They include key frames, animation CSS properties, and other complicated stuff.  Google 'css animation'. This will be very long if I explained the whole thing.